# How do I push this new value onto array?

Tags: angularjs

I have this function in my Angular controller;

```
        $scope.addPart = function (part) {
        $http.get('stock/' + this.part.oemnumber).success(function (result) {
            $scope.stock = result;
        });
        $scope.woParts.push({"id":part.id, "name":part.partname, "partno":part.partno, "oemnumber":part.oemnumber,
        "stock":part.stock, "price":stock.unitcost});
        $scope.part = '';
    };
```

It will successfully return the associated stock record and I can get stock.unitcost to output in the console and display in the view.  My issue is, I need to push the value onto the woParts array.

I am getting stock undefined with the current syntax.  When I try to change it to "price":$scope.stock.unitcost it does not throw an error but still does not work.

What am I missing?

I have also tried to define it before hand but that doesn't work either...

```
        $scope.addPart = function (part) {
        $http.get('stock/' + this.part.oemnumber).success(function (result) {
            $scope.stock = result;
            $scope.part.price = $scope.stock.unitcost;
        });
        $scope.woParts.push({"id":part.id, "name":part.partname, "partno":part.partno, "oemnumber":part.oemnumber,
        "stock":part.stock, "price":part.price});
        $scope.part = '';
    };
```

Should I be separating the stock get and the push into 2 functions?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be $scope.stock.unitCost. Can you please log and check the result you are getting from the $http.get call?.

Comment: Yep, $scope.stock.unitcost is correct and returns the value I want.  Answered below - push needs to be moved into http call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `$scope.stock` inside the success function, which is called async, so the next line where you `push`, `stock` is not yet initialized, as it would be initialized after the `http` call returns.
Instead you could do:

```
$scope.addPart = function (part) {
        $http.get('stock/' + this.part.oemnumber).success(function (result) {
            $scope.stock = result;
            $scope.woParts.push({"id":part.id, "name":part.partname, "partno":part.partno, "oemnumber":part.oemnumber,
        "stock":part.stock, "price":stock.unitcost});
        });

    };
```

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Thanks, I wrote the 2 bits separately as I was going and should have put them together.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems here. The first is that you are using `stock.unitcost` and I think you really want `$scope.stock.unitcost`. The second problem is that `$http.get` is asynchronous and the promise will not be resolved before you try to use `$scope.stock.unitcost` (once you have made that fix). Here is how I believe you will want to refactor your snippet (you need to move the functionality inside of the promise successful resolve function):

```
$scope.addPart = function (part) {
    $http.get('stock/' + this.part.oemnumber)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.stock = response.data;
                $scope.part.price = $scope.stock.unitcost;
                $scope.woParts.push({
                    "id":part.id, 
                    "name":part.partname, 
                    "partno":part.partno, 
                    "oemnumber":part.oemnumber, 
                    "stock":part.stock, 
                    "price":part.price});
                $scope.part = '';
            },
            function(error) {
                // handle the error from your $http.get
            });
};
```

Comment: Correct, gaurav5430 just beat you to it.